# How can I prevent flexboxes from taking the remaining width of the row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want every cell to be 1/3 of the row. I tried achieving this with flexbox but the boxes with the css property "flex:1" act like they have "width:50%".

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/NfeVh/1073/

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">

      </div>
      <div class="cell">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.row {
    background: #ccc; 
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: they take up the remaining space.

IF you add 3 children to the flex container and give them all a property of flex-grow1 they will take up one 3rd of the container

Comment: Is there a way to make 2 cells take up 2/3 of the row and leave the 1/3 the row empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100%/3);
}
```

Use `flex: 0 0 calc(100%/3)`

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfeVh/1394/

Comment: Can you explain what "flex: 0 0 calc(100%/3)" does? It worked tough

Comment: This is the shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`

Comment: Also if you want to align the items on right. Then use `justify-content: flex-end;` on `.row` .

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfeVh/1396/

Comment: And how can I let the 4th cell in this fiddle shift to the next row (so under the 3 others) : jsfiddle.net/deL6sL94

Comment: Use `flex-flow: row wrap` on `.row` , This will work, And also make sure you use `box-sizing: border-box` on `.cell` , otherwise `.cell`'s border will also be counted as its width. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfeVh/1398/